# How many twin prime pairs between $6n$ and $36n^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, twin-primes

Is this a valid method to calculate a lower bound on the number of twin prime pairs that occur over $(6n$, $36n^2]$?

Divide the number line into groups of six, each of which contains a potential twin prime pair at $6i\pm1$ for $i = 1, 2, 3...\infty$.  For any prime number $p$, the fraction of groups that contain multiples of $p$ landing on a potential prime (I will refer to this as a collision) is $2/p$.  The fraction of groups having no collision is $\frac{p-2}{p}$.  Over a finite number of groups $N$, the maximum number of groups containing a collision is $\lceil N\frac{2}{p} \rceil$. The minimum number of groups containing no collision is $\lfloor N\frac{p-2}{p} \rfloor$.

To enable the calculation for the groups over $(6n$, $36n^2]$, consider the set of all numbers equal to $6i\pm1$ for $i = 1,2,3...n$, which is a superset of the primes over $[5, 6n]$.  Using a superset of the primes will eliminate more groups than necessary, yielding a lower bound on the number of surviving groups containing twin prime pairs.  For a given $i$, the minimum number of groups surviving collisions with $6i-1$ is

$$N\frac{6i-3}{6i-1}-1$$

The minimum number of groups that survive collisions with $6i+1$ is

$$N\frac{6i-1}{6i+1}-1$$

Considering $6i\pm1$ together, the minimum number of groups that survive is

$$N\frac{6i-3}{6i-1} \frac{6i-1}{6i+1} - 2$$

Over $(6n$, $36n^2]$, $N=6n^2-n$.  Considering $i = 1,2,3...n$, the minimum number of groups containing twin prime pairs is

$$(6n^2-n)\prod_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{6i-3}{6i+1}} - 2n$$

Comment: Can you prove that the minimum number of groups containing no collision is $\lfloor N\cdot\frac{p-2}{p}\rfloor$? $\lfloor N/p\rfloor (p-1)$ I would believe, but this looks like it could be false if the interval is chosen just wrong.

Comment: I believe such a bound (except if it's $0$, but that's not an interesting bound) would imply the existence of an infinite number of twin primes. It is (unless proven so recently it hasn't been updated on wikipedia) unknown whether that is the case.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  What does "the fraction of groups that contain multiples of 
 landing on a potential prime"  mean?

Comment: See [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4769202/) with a similar conjecture for relevant thoughts.

Comment: @Mastrem no, no I cannot.  This looks like the next direction to look into.   Thanks!

Comment: @lulu Picture the number line divided into groups of six.  Each group has two potential primes (and a potential twin prime pair) at 6n+/-1.  If a multiple of a prime number p lands on either of the potential primes, that group cannot contain a twin prime pair.  The fraction referred to is the fraction of groups - either over the entire number line or over a given interval - containing such a multiple.

Comment: There are lots of ways to divide the number line into groups of $6$.  Did you specifically mean groups of the form $\{6k, 6k+1, 6k+2, \cdots, 6k+5\}$?  Some other specific group?  Of course, my example can't contain a twin prime pair, but with other divisions, they could.  And what does "groups over $(6n, 36n^2]$" mean?